# Start-up message : Reset USB port-power 1000ms

Tags: raspbian, boot

[image]

I run Raspbian on a RPI, and last night I executed a CURL command - it hung, and then the RPI was offline. I've repeatedly restarted the RPI, but this comes up every time. If I swap the SD card, it works fine. If the SD card is now corrupt, this is the second one in as many months....

Exactly what is this screen? It doesn't appear to tell me anything informational such as the OS is toast. The only "advice" is Reset USB port-power 1000ms, so I did cycle it a few times - with the same result.

Comment: You forgot to ask the question. If the question is is "what to do now?" you could try to recover your files from it (or a backup), then reinstall the system.

Comment: I guess my question is - is this screen a warning that the OS is corrupt? It doesn't seem to say anything?

Comment: Please edit the question and add the question.  Do not expect people to read comments.

Comment: Pretty obvious what he's asking, comments like above are gatekeeper-like and don't actually solve any problems.

Answer (score -1):

**TL;DR**
Took the SD card out, switched on, plugged the SD card in without powering down and it booted - no clue why.

This doesn't answer the question (of why this screen doesn't show any errors), but solved the issue in my case.

The long version:
I had the same issue - and exactly the same screen. It's really strange, but I thought I'd see what happened if I took the SD card out altogether and try starting the Pi. I got a similar screen (with SD card not detected on it as expected). At the bottom of the screen I noticed a couple of extra lines that (I think) indicated that it was trying to boot from other sources. When these lines scrolled up and were duplicated, I got the feeling it was trying to boot again, so I plugged the SD card in without pulling the power (if the card was already corrupted, then what did I have to lose?). The screen now indicated that the SD Card was detected, and the Pi booted!

No idea why the behaviour was like this, but as long as it worked...

And yep, for all of you "put in the right question" type commenters - since you've got enough time to put in these less-than-useful comments, I'd suggest you look at places on the forum where you can actually contribute.